# Is it possible for a method to stop another method from being called if a condition is true?

Tags: java

I've been given an assignment to edit a game and add different elements to it, one was the ability to restore player life when interacting with an object which I have completed.

The next step is to stop this from working when the players life is max (100).

My idea then was to create a method with a condition (and if it is true, stop my life adding method from working / being called.)

Example:

```
 private void checkMaxLife() {
    if (playerLife==100) {
      //Stop method addLife from working
    }
  }
```

Would this be possible and what is the syntax?

EDIT:
This was the fix, added playerLife < 100 to the collision method instead.

```
private void foodAddLife() {
    //Check food collisions
    for (int i = 0; i < food.length; ++i) {

      if (playerLife < 100 && food[i].getX() == player.getX() && food[i].getY() == player.getY()) {

        //We have a collision
        ++playerLife;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why not check if `playerLife == 100` directly in `addLife()` and get out of that method if the condition is true? That seems much simpler and straightforward than your current approach. Or you can wrap the call to `addLife()` in a conditional statement that checks if `playerLife == 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't need `checkMaxLife`, just use the attribute `playerLife` in the method `addLife`

```
private void addLife() {
    if (playerLife < 100) {
        playerLife++;  // or whatever value
    }
}
```

---

With 2 methods, you see that one is useless

```
private boolean isFullLife() {
    return playerLife >= 100;
}

private void addLife() {
    if (!isFullLife()) {
        playerLife++;  // or whatever value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now, just added && playerLife < 100 in the addLife condition.

Comment: @FrederikBA added where ? That condition was already here

Comment: To the collition detection

Comment: @FrederikBA ok. You can now think about accepting th answer if is helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just return the function when player life is **MAX_VALUE**.

```
private void addLife() {
    if(playerLife>=100)
        return;
    // Do Whatever you need to do
}
```